# Using a Picture Box as a button, how do I ignore/disable double-click events?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, object, windows-ce

I'm having some difficulty using picture boxes as buttons.  I'd like to have custom button graphics rather than using the plain-old windows forms Button control.

It works pretty well, except the buttons seem to lag when a single button is pressed rapidly.  I'd like the OnClick method to be called immediately every time the Picture Box is clicked, but it seems to be registering a double-click event, even though I am not using that event.

The short version is I'd like to:

- (Ideal) Disable the double-click event, since it appears this is what the Control is waiting for on every alternating click of the Picture Box and I never use it. Or,
- (Acceptable) Write a generic DoubleClick event I can use for all Picture Boxes I plan to use as buttons.

I did write up a test program which shows that this is, in fact, what's happening.  I wrote a MouseUp event that increments a counter by 1, and also added a OnClick even that increments a different counter by 1.  When rapidly clicking the Picture Box linked to these events, the MouseUp counter is exactly double that of the OnClick counter.

I then added a DoubleClick event that calls the OnClick event.  This, although not ideal, solves the problem perfectly well.  If there is a way to write a generic DoubleClick event that all buttons could use, I think this would be acceptable.

Right now my DoubleClick event is just

```
    private void pb_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pbOK_Click(sender, e);  //This needs to be generic
    }
```

I'd like to at least replace the DoubleClick line with something like

```
    private void pb_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (Sender.ToString)_Click(sender, e); // Doesn't work quite like this.
    }
```

I could write a special DoubleClick event for each Picture Box individually, but that is far from ideal and seems quite cumbersome, so I would prefer not to do that if it isn't necessary.

This is my first posted question, so thanks to anyone who takes the time to read this.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This program is being developed for Windows CE, so the properties and events options for the objects is quite limited.  I still may be missing something, but as far as I can tell the Properties list for buttons goes straight from GenerateMember to Location, with none of the Image options available.  I apologize for not stating the target platform in the original post.

Comment: Were you aware that the Button class has properties (like Image) that let it look as you wish while still acting like a button?

Comment: @JohnArlen I double checked that just to be sure, then I realized I didn't specify the target platform, Windows CE, so I edited it in.  Sorry about that.  Unfortunately, to make it Compact some useful properties and control methods have been removed.  I've also run into an issue of trying to sort detail ListViews by clicking on the header.  As far as I can tell, no sort method exists.  I have found a potential work-around for that, however.  Hopefully it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done with the Control.SetStyle() method, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyButton : PictureBox {
    public MyButton() {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I ended up just copying the PictureBox OnClick event method to the DoubleClick event call of the same PictureBox.  This way I didn't have to do anything too fancy.  Although I probably created some unnecessary event handlers, the program works exactly as I was hoping it would.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my original answer was trash. My update:

Here's a link on how to get a controls Method name:
 [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/72040/how-to-get-method-name-of-control-event-handler)

In the link it has a Control c. To get your control (sender) use the following:

```
PictureBox picbox = (PictureBox) sender;
```

Next, call a method using a string(your class.Method.Name): [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19911/Dynamically-Invoke-A-Method-Given-Strings-with-Met)

Now that should work. Hope it does.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your own control? This way, you don't have to do anything to get the behavior you want.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class ButtonPictureBox : PictureBox
    {
        protected override void OnDoubleClick(System.EventArgs e)
        {
            OnClick(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is possible on Windows CE though.

If you also want to hide the `DoubleClick` event in the form designer, you can add this to the class:

```
        [Browsable(false)]
        public new event EventHandler DoubleClick;
```